# The fundamental theorem of algebra, any real polynomial can be written in factors of degree of $1$ or $2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis

Does the theorem that any real polynomial can be written in factors of degree of $1$ or $2$ really only hold only for polynomials with real coefficients. Why doesn't it hold for a polynomial with complex coefficients?

If I understand this theorem correctly, it's meant that it is written only in multiplication between factors (no addition) and that those factors that are multiplied together have the degree either $1$ or $2$, and we can always get any polynomial in that form. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: It does hold for a polynomial with complex coefficients. You just don’t need quadratic factors.

Comment: The point is that a real polynomial is a product of *real* polynomials of degree 1 or 2.

Comment: Any complex polynomial can be written as a product of complex polynomials of degree 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what the situation is for real and complex polynomials:

- Any real polynomial can be written as the product of real polynomials of degree $1$ or $2$.
- Any complex polynomials can be written as the product of complex polynomials of degree $1$.

And, since any real polynomial is in particular a complex polynomial:

- Any real polynomial can be written as the product of *complex* polynomials of degree $1$.